# Path to multiple folders in file plugin of logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

So I want to use something like :

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/blah/*/blah/blah/blah/*/*"
        ...
      }
}
```

Is this possible? If not then what is the way to do this?

I know I can use multiple file plugins inside input but I have more than 50 log files to read from. Writing them one by one will be too much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible (see [ruby globbing rules](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob)). Try this

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/blah/**/blah/blah/blah/**/*.*"
        ...
      }
}
```